# Rails RestClient pass token in header fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I do this curl in Terminal which works excellent:

```
$ curl https://myurl.com/api/v1/orders/53e0ae7f6630361c46060000 -H "Authorization: Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Output is json.

Now I want to access the json string via my rails app. I have tried RestClient to do this, but somehow I always get a 401 unauthorized error. I believe the token gets not send correctly via header. I have tried the following:

```
RestClient.get 'https://myurl.com/api/v1/orders/53e0ae7f6630361c46060000', {token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

and

```
RestClient.get 'https://myurl.com/api/v1/orders/53e0ae7f6630361c46060000', :params => {:token => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

with no success. Maybe I use a wrong syntax for sending the token in the header?
Doku is here http://rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client - I could not find any mistakes.

Comment: Have you tried this? `RestClient.get 'https://myurl.com/api/v1/orders/53e0ae7f6630361c46060000', { Authorization: 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }`

Comment: Yes, authorisation works there but I get this: "incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT" :/

Answer (score 6):

```
# GET request with modified headers
RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}

# POST request with modified headers
RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', {:foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux'}, {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}

# DELETE request with modified headers
RestClient.delete 'http://example.com/resource', {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}
```

Source: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#headers